# Is returning a static string from a function in C a bad practice?

Tags: c, string, static

I'm working on a C program where I've implemented a function to generate ANSI color codes for printing colored text.

```c
const char* getAnsiColorCode(int colorId) {
    static char colorCode[15];
    snprintf(colorCode, sizeof(colorCode), "\e[38;5;%dm", colorId);
    return colorCode;
}
```

All I need to do for my task is to print some colored hello worlds:

```c
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        printf("%sHello, World!\n", getAnsiColorCode(i));
    }
}
```

This is the cleanest solution I could find but I am wondering if declaring `colorCode` as `static` there is not a bad practice.
Will every initialization of `colorCode` override the same variable or will the previous `colorCode`s stay in the memory? I don't really like the idea of all of them staying there. But if `colorCode` gets overwritten it doesn't seem bad.

I also tried some other solutions, but I don't like them as much.
I don't want to allocate `colorCode` on the heap and then free it.
I also don't want to pass it as an argument, because it looks less clean that way.
Is there a better way of doing it than `static` and is `static` here not a bad practice?

Comment: As long as you understand that each time you call that function any pointers previously returned will point to whatever the new contents are. It's also not thread safe if that is an issue in your program.

Comment: Making this `static` causes a lot of problems as soon as you need two color codes at the same time. For example, if you want to use two colors in the same `printf` call, or if two threads want to print colored text at the same time (perhaps to two different output streams).

Comment: This question may be a better fit for [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), since it's a general design / recommendation question. On this site it may be closed as opinion-based.

Comment: using the `\e` escape sequence is not portable. Better use `\x1B` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with this approach is you have a hidden `static` state that makes your function neither thread safe not multi callable in the same expression, including indirectly.

Consider for example this code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        printf("%sHello, World!%s\n", getAnsiColorCode(i), getAnsiColorCode(0));
    }
}
```

The output will be indeterminate as the order of calls for the `getAnsiColorCode` is unspecified, but in all cases the espace sequence output by `printf` will be the same for both `%s` replacements.

It is OK to return a static string as long as its value is constant, ie: does not change across calls.

There are 2 ways to achieve your escape sequence code:

- using an argument array of sufficient length where the sequence is constructed

  ```
  char *getAnsiColorCode(char colorCode[static 15], int colorId) {
      snprintf(colorCode, 15), "\e[38;5;%dm", colorId);
      return colorCode;
  }

  int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
      for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
          char colorCode[15];
          printf("%sHello, World!\n", getAnsiColorCode(colorCode, i));
      }
  }
  ```
- Using a static array of answers (not fully thread safe, but callable multiple times without restrictions):

  ```
  const char *getAnsiColorCode(int colorId) {
      static char colorCode[256][12];
      colorId %= 255;
      if (!*colorCode[colorId]) {
          snprintf(colorCode[colorId], sizeof colorCode[colorId],
                   "\e[38;5;%dm", colorId);
      }
      return colorCode[colorId];
  }

  int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
      for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
          printf("%sHello, World!\n", getAnsiColorCode(i));
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Now everything is clear to me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a "helper function", obviating the concern about using one (or more) `static` buffers.

C is a powerful language. Always strive to make use of its facilities.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define CLR(i,str) "\033[38;5;%dm" str, i

int main( void ) {

    for( int i = 0; i < 256; i++ )
        printf( CLR( i, "Hello, World! (%d)\n" ), i );

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Hello, World! (0) // black
Hello, World! (1) // dark red ... use your imagination or give it a try...
Hello, World! (2) // dark green
Hello, World! (3) // ...
Hello, World! (4)
Hello, World! (5)
Hello, World! (6)
Hello, World! (7)
/* ... */
```

Quoting Peter Parkers' uncle, "*With great power comes great responsibility.*" Macros can blow up if not handled correctly. Caveat emptor.

**EDIT**
Or... If you want the code that calls the colouration of text to "look nicer", you could use `VARGS`...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void printfCLR( int clr, char *fmt, ... ) {
    fprintf( stdout, "\033[38;5;%dm", clr ); // output the colour prefix

    va_list ap;
    va_start( ap, fmt );
    vfprintf( stdout, fmt, ap ); // output the string (with arguments)
    va_end( ap );
}

int main( void ) {

    for( int clr = 0; clr < 256; clr++ )
        printfCLR( clr, "Hello, World!\n" );  // 'clean' invocation...

    return 0;
}
```

If you want to see something out of the psychedelic 60s...

```
    for( int i = 0; i < 256; i++ ) {
        printfCLR( 255-i, "Hello, " );
        printfCLR(     i, "World!\n" );
    }
```